# How does printf returns the count of the number of characters successfully printed?

Tags: c

For the below code snippet :

```
int a=printf("made,%d,easy",printf("Lucknow"));
printf("%d",a);
```

I am getting the value of a as 11 using GCC Compiler, I am not getting the logic behind this, `printf` returns the number of characters printed on the screen, so it prints `lucknowmade,7,easy`. Therefore, we have 18 characters printed on the screen so the value of a should be 18, why is it giving OP as 11?

Please explain this briefly.

Comment: There are two printf calls which print separately. They return separate values.

Comment: `made,7,easy` -- this is all it printed

Answer (score 4):

The code first executes `printf("Lucknow")` which prints "Lucknow" on the screen and returns the value 7 to the second `printf()` call. The second `printf()` prints "made,7,easy" and returns 11 which is the number of characters it printed. It doesn't know or care what the other function did.

Answer (score 1):

As you have stated, `printf` returns the number of characters printed.

```
printf("made,%d,easy",printf("Lucknow"))
```

returns 11 because `printf("Lucknow")` prints "Lucknow" then returns 7, and so you would end up printing "made,7,easy" which is 11 characters.